# How to change the font of the main title in plot()

Tags: r

From [this page](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/R/) I have come to understand that:

```
font.main=4
```

will give me a italic bold title for my figure. However I want neither but a plain-old-sans-serif font. More generally I have been looking for a table of what values does what but not found any so far. Is there one and if so where can I see it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`?par` has

> ```
> ‘font’ An integer which specifies which font to use for text.  If
>      possible, device drivers arrange so that 1 corresponds to
>      plain text (the default), 2 to bold face, 3 to italic and 4
>      to bold italic.  Also, font 5 is expected to be the symbol
>      font, in Adobe symbol encoding.  On some devices font
>      families can be selected by ‘family’ to choose different sets
>      of 5 fonts.
> ```

All of which applies to `font.main`. Compare:

```
> layout(1:2)
> plot(1:10, font.main = 1, main = "Foo") ## plain font
> plot(1:10, main = "Foo")                ## default bold font
> layout(1)
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: it's worth looking at the `extrafont` package too

Answer (score 13):

There are two relevant parameters that govern the font. `font` and `family`. You may want to change `family` instead of `font`.

From [Quick-R on graphical parameters](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html):

> **font:**     Integer specifying font to use for text. 1=plain, 2=bold,
>   3=italic, 4=bold italic, 5=symbol
>   ...
>   **family:**   font family for drawing text. Standard values are "serif", "sans", "mono", "symbol". Mapping is device dependent.

Furthermore:

> In windows, mono is mapped to "TT Courier New", serif is mapped to"TT
>   Times New Roman", sans is mapped to "TT Arial", mono is mapped to "TT
>   Courier New", and symbol is mapped to "TT Symbol" (TT=True Type). You
>   can add your own mappings.

```
# Type family examples - creating new mappings
plot(1:10,1:10,type="n")
windowsFonts(
  A=windowsFont("Arial Black"),
  B=windowsFont("Bookman Old Style"),
  C=windowsFont("Comic Sans MS"),
  D=windowsFont("Symbol")
)
text(3,3,"Hello World Default")
text(4,4,family="A","Hello World from Arial Black")
text(5,5,family="B","Hello World from Bookman Old Style")
text(6,6,family="C","Hello World from Comic Sans MS")
text(7,7,family="D", "Hello World from Symbol")
```

see also `?par`.

Side note: [Quick R](http://www.statmethods.net/index.html), especially the stuff on Graphics, is a great resource for a lot of R related information.