# How do I perfect the following R plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have the following plot in R:

```
x = c(0, 1e-10, 1e-08, 1e-06, 1e-05, 0.001, 0.1);
y = c(22000, 21490, 17252, 9204, 6118, 5092, 4998);
z = c(85.59, 85.59, 85.58, 85.49, 85.29, 85.29, 85.29);

x1 = c(0, 1e-10, 1e-08, 1e-06, 1e-05, 0.001, 0.1);
y2 = c(22000, 20039, 15185, 7705, 5436, 5223, 4933);
z2 = c(85.59, 85.59, 85.58, 85.53, 85.46, 85.49, 85.49);

y = y / 60;

y2 = y2 / 60;


x = log(x);

par("mar")
par(mar = c(par("mar")[1:3], 5.1))

plot(x,y, type="n", lwd=4, ylab="", xlab="threshold", xaxt="n",yaxt="n")

axis(1,lwd=4)
axis(2,lwd=4)

points(x, y, type = "l", lwd=4)

points(x, y, col="red", cex=2, pch=19)

points(x, y2, lwd=4, type="o", lty=2, col="black");

points(x, y2, col="red", cex=2, pch=19);

par("usr")
par(usr = c(par("usr")[1:2], 84,86))

axis(4, lwd=4)
points(x, z, type="l", lwd=4)

points(x, z, col="blue", cex=2, pch=15)

points(x, z2, type="l", col="black", lty=2, lwd=4)

points(x, z2, col="blue", cex=2, pch=15)


mtext("Measure1", side = 4, col = "blue",line=3)
mtext("Measure2", side = 2, col = "red",line=3)
```

It is almost perfect for me, but I just want to tweak it according to the following things:

1. The left y axis and the x axis - they are bolder, but for some reason, the bold part is not stretching *all* over the axes.
2. I want to make the font of the numbers and the labels a bit bigger, and maybe in bold font face.
3. I may even want to change the font to Times, but it sounds to me like a lot of hassle, from what I have seen online.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. `box` is your friend - if you add `lwd=4` and `type="l"` as options. 2. `?par` is your friend. `cex.lab`and `cex.axis` in your axis statements will address this I think. 3. Not sure off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by @thelatemail in the comment above, your first question can be answered by the function `box`:

```
box(lwd=4)
```

If you want only the sides with the axes to be bold, then you want to add a `bty` parameter:

```
box(lwd=4, bty="u") # For all the different kind of boxes see ?par.
```

To change the font and the size of the labels you have to use parameters `font` and `cex.lab` or `cex.axis` in your `plot` and `axis` statements:

```
axis(1, font=2, cex.axis=1.1) #font=2 correspond to bold face. See ?par for more information
```

And finaly for the font, you can use argument `family`, however it will work differently with all kinds of output device. You will find more information on that subject in section "Fonts" of `?x11` and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121913/1451109).

```
axis(1, family="Times") #This will work with Cairo devices for example.
```

Here is your plot with `cex.axis` set up at 1.1, bold fonts and bold U-shaped box and in Times font:
[image]