# Change of Font in R - Bubble Charts

Tags: r

I'm breaking my head trying to change the font of all the titles (main so as axis-titles) in this Bubble Chart. I would like to use "Neutraface Text Demi Alt", size +14. Could someone please help me? Do you know maybe any fancy Bubble Chart code?

```
crime <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/crimeRatesByState2005.tsv", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
radius <- sqrt( crime$population/ pi )
2
[1] 2
symbols(crime$murder, crime$burglary, circles=radius, inches=0.35, fg="white", bg="grey", xlab="Murder Rate", ylab="Burglary Rate")
text(crime$murder, crime$burglary, crime$state, cex=0.5)
```

Comment: Sorry, but how is this off-topic and why is this not a real question? It's within an R-plot.

Comment: Not sure if it directly answers your question about getting *this* font you ask for, but maybe this helps a bit? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7121913/559784

Comment: Another relevant post: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2011-July/008369.html (if you're on a mac)

Comment: for fonts, check out the `extrafont` package: https://github.com/wch/extrafont

Comment: Following up: I started to try to do this, but had trouble getting a copy of Neutraface Text Demi Alt I could use -- it's available only as an OTF file, which even the development version of `extrafonts` couldn't handle ...

Answer (score 1):

At least on my MacOS setup, with R3.0.0,  I have success with

```
plot(x,y,family='Times')
```

or many other fonts currently installed.  Oddly, Symbol didn't display (got the usual empty rectangles).